# Adding a separator between content children

Tags: angular, angular-template

In `ItemsComponent` there is an `ng-content` directive and I am interested in automatically inserting an `<hr>` element between every content child. I believe the best place to handle it will be in the ItemsComponent itself.

Is there a way to do that that doesn't involve hiding the last `<hr>` with `display: none`?

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-oyypmx

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to hide last `<hr>` using CSS, why not send a parameter in `<app-item>` directive
`<app-item 'showHR'></app-item>`.
And if parameter is available then show `<hr>` after your item.

Second way is to use top and bottom border for each item, then you don't have to worry about hiding it after last item.

Edit :
You can achieve it using **CSS**. You will not be able to add a `<hr>`, but you can use `border-bottom` after each `<app-item>` and then do not show it after last element.

```
app-item {
display: flex; 
 margin: 3px 0px; 
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

app-item:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

[image]

Comment: because then it would require the consumer of the component to do something that would ideally be done automatically.

Comment: Added one more approach using CSS, please check.

Comment: this is pretty close to what I currently have which is `:host:last-child > hr { display: none }`, I just thought maybe there is a way to do it using the `ViewContainerRef.indexOf` or something similar

Comment: In my opinion, it would be complicating a fairly easy task. Unless there is a very strong reason to do so.